# Laravel: 401 Unauthorized ajax-запрос

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Роут:

```
Route::post('vote', ['as' => 'vote', 'uses' => 'HomeController@vote']);
```

Метод:

```
public function vote()
{
    echo 'yes';
}
```

Вьюха:

```
<form class="mstar">
    @include('layouts.partials.rating')
</form>
```

`rating.blade.php`:

```
<input id="input_id" class="rating" value="" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="0.1">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <script>
        $('#input_id').rating({
            ...
        }).on("rating.change", function (event, value) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/vote',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {'rating': value, '_token' : $('input[name=_token]').val()}
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Ответ: `401 (Unauthorized)`

Comment: А посредники (`middleware`) есть какие-то?

Comment: @Станислав нету, остальные запросы, которые так же лежат в `web`, обрабатываются нормально

Comment: `Web` - это что у вас?

Comment: @Станислав решил вопрос, перенес метод в другой контроллер, все ок. Видимо проблема в контроллере была: `$this->middleware('auth');` в `__construct`, как вы сказали. Спасибо. Web - middleware имел ввиду

Comment: Да, я про это и имел ввиду. Вынесу свой комментарий в ответ тогда, сможете отметить его как правильный и/или оценить.

Comment: Мне не помогает, и $this->middleware('auth') на месте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте контроллер на предмет использования в нем посредников (`middleware`). Если он не указан при определении маршрута (а судя по вашему коду, этого нет), то обычно он указывается в конструкторе (функция `__construct()`) самого контроллера, ищите строку вроде `$this->middleware('auth');`.